# Dynamically add case statement sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am new to sql server, having a requirement like as follows,

Need to select list of records from db, using case when statement. for example;

```
select * from test where test.id in (case when @id = '' then test.id else @id end);
```

Here @id will be comma separated value like this (123,124,125,126).

If I pass only one value ie. @id = 123. It is working fine and get failed when passing array of elements. Can anyone suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below approach.

```
select * from test where @id = '' OR ',' + @id LIKE '%,' + test.id + '%'
```

Comment: Here it checks the `test.id` to the list of values. If `@id` has values `123,124,125,126` the it adds a leading comma to it so it is now `,123,124,125,126` and the like statement adds a leading comma to the `test.id` column, so lets say the `test.id` is `125` the condition becomes `',123,124,125,126' LIKE '%,125%'` and so on.

Comment: Thanks patel, this work if @id has some value. I checked now with `@id = ''` and it is getting failed

Comment: That is surprising! `@id = '' OR` condition is there for the same. If there is a space character then try `LTRIM(@id) = '' OR`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You create function for split string to xml

   ```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].StringSplitXML
    (
           @String  VARCHAR(MAX), @Separator CHAR(1)
    )
    RETURNS @RESULT TABLE(Value VARCHAR(MAX))
      AS
       BEGIN

        DECLARE @XML XML
        SET @XML = CAST(
           ('' + REPLACE(@String, @Separator, '') + '')
           AS XML)
   ```

   ```
    INSERT INTO @RESULT
    SELECT t.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
    FROM @XML.nodes('i') AS t(i)
    WHERE t.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') <> ''

    RETURN
   END
   ```
2. after create function you can change script

`declare @querystring  varchar(2000)
declare @id varchar(200)    
set @querystring ='select * from test where id ' + 
(
    case when @id = '' then 'in (id)' else  ' in (select value from StringSplitXML('''+@id+''','',''))' end
)    
EXECUTE( @querystring)`